# Eliminate one list according to another list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have two dimensional list like that

```
x_irp_group = [['x1_1_4', 'x1_2_4', 'x1_3_4', 'x1_4_4', 'x1_5_4', 'x1_6_4', 'x1_7_4', 'x1_8_4', 'x1_9_4', 'x1_10_4', 'x1_1_5', 'x1_2_5', 'x1_3_5', 'x1_4_5', 'x1_5_5', 'x1_6_5', 'x1_7_5', 'x1_8_5', 'x1_9_5', 'x1_10_5', 'x1_1_6', 'x1_2_6', 'x1_3_6', 'x1_4_6', 'x1_5_6', 'x1_6_6', 'x1_7_6', 'x1_8_6', 'x1_9_6', 'x1_10_6', 'x1_1_7', 'x1_2_7', 'x1_3_7', 'x1_4_7', 'x1_5_7', 'x1_6_7', 'x1_7_7', 'x1_8_7', 'x1_9_7', 'x1_10_7', 'x1_1_8', 'x1_2_8', 'x1_3_8', 'x1_4_8', 'x1_5_8', 'x1_6_8', 'x1_7_8', 'x1_8_8', 'x1_9_8', 'x1_10_8'], ['x1_1_8', 'x1_2_8', 'x1_3_8', 'x1_4_8', 'x1_5_8', 'x1_6_8', 'x1_7_8', 'x1_8_8', 'x1_9_8', 'x1_10_8', 'x1_1_9', 'x1_2_9', 'x1_3_9', 'x1_4_9', 'x1_5_9', 'x1_6_9', 'x1_7_9', 'x1_8_9', 'x1_9_9', 'x1_10_9', 'x1_1_10', 'x1_2_10', 'x1_3_10', 'x1_4_10', 'x1_5_10', 'x1_6_10', 'x1_7_10', 'x1_8_10', 'x1_9_10', 'x1_10_10', 'x1_1_11', 'x1_2_11', 'x1_3_11', 'x1_4_11', 'x1_5_11', 'x1_6_11', 'x1_7_11', 'x1_8_11', 'x1_9_11', 'x1_10_11', 'x1_1_12', 'x1_2_12', 'x1_3_12', 'x1_4_12', 'x1_5_12', 'x1_6_12', 'x1_7_12', 'x1_8_12', 'x1_9_12', 'x1_10_12']]
```

I wanna eliminate this two dimensional list if the elements in another one dimensional list like that

```
x_irp_eliminated_list =   ['x1_1_4', 'x1_1_8', 'x1_1_12', 'x1_1_16', 'x1_1_19', 'x1_1_22', 'x1_1_26', 'x1_1_30', 'x1_1_34', 'x1_1_37', 'x1_1_43', 'x1_1_49', 'x1_1_55', 'x1_1_61', 'x1_1_68', 'x1_1_75', 'x1_1_81', 'x1_1_87', 'x1_1_92', 'x1_1_96', 'x1_1_101', 'x1_1_107', 'x1_1_112', 'x1_1_116', 'x1_1_121', 'x1_1_126', 'x1_1_131', 'x1_1_134', 'x1_1_137', 'x1_1_141', 'x1_1_145', 'x1_1_149', 'x1_1_152', 'x1_1_155', 'x1_1_160', 'x1_1_164', 'x1_1_169', 'x1_1_173', 'x1_1_181', 'x1_1_189', 'x1_1_197', 'x1_1_205', 'x1_2_8', 'x1_2_10', 'x1_2_13', 'x1_2_17', 'x1_2_21', 'x1_2_25', 'x1_2_28', 'x1_2_30', 'x1_2_34', 'x1_2_40', 'x1_2_45', 'x1_2_51', 'x1_2_58', 'x1_2_66', 'x1_2_71', 'x1_2_77', 'x1_2_82', 'x1_2_86', 'x1_2_91', 'x1_2_97', 'x1_2_102', 'x1_2_106', 'x1_2_111', 'x1_2_117', 'x1_2_122', 'x1_2_125', 'x1_2_129', 'x1_2_132', 'x1_2_135', 'x1_2_139', 'x1_2_143', 'x1_2_147', 'x1_2_151', 'x1_2_154', 'x1_2_157', 'x1_2_161', 'x1_2_166', 'x1_2_172', 'x1_2_177', 'x1_2_181', 'x1_2_189', 'x1_2_197', 'x1_2_205', 'x1_2_214', 'x1_3_1', 'x1_3_4', 'x1_3_8', 'x1_3_11', 'x1_3_15', 'x1_3_18', 'x1_3_22', 'x1_3_25', 'x1_3_28', 'x1_3_32', 'x1_3_35', 'x1_3_39', 'x1_3_42', 'x1_3_46', 'x1_3_49', 'x1_3_52', 'x1_3_56', 'x1_3_59', 'x1_3_63', 'x1_3_66', 'x1_3_70', 'x1_3_73', 'x1_3_77', 'x1_3_81', 'x1_3_85', 'x1_3_88', 'x1_3_91', 'x1_3_94', 'x1_3_97', 'x1_3_101', 'x1_3_105', 'x1_3_109', 'x1_3_112', 'x1_3_115', 'x1_3_118', 'x1_3_122', 'x1_3_126', 'x1_3_130', 'x1_3_134', 'x1_3_137', 'x1_3_140', 'x1_3_143', 'x1_3_147', 'x1_3_151', 'x1_3_156', 'x1_3_159', 'x1_3_163']
```

I write a code like that but it did not work well.

```
x_final = [i for i, j in zip(x_irp_group, x_irp_eliminated_list) if i == j]
```

I shorten the lists. Normally their sizes are much bigger than that

Comment: do these represents sets or is the order important? set operations would make this much simpler because I think you can just do `{1,2,3,4} - {3,2}` to remove elements.

Comment: order is important. For example x1_2_4 is not in second list. So the code has to delete it from x_irp_group.

Comment: but it is important that `x1_2_4` comes before `x1_3_4` in the list? if the order of the elements doesn't matter (or occasionally you just want to iterate over it sorted) then using sets might be a nicer approach here.

Comment: Thanks for detail answer. The order is important. So I should not use set approach, should i?

Comment: the `sorted` function exists, so if most of the operations are easier with sets (like exclusion, intersection, union etc.) and occasionally you need to iterate over it in order you just sort it as needed, then maybe that'd be the way to go but if you don't obviously do those kinds of operations a lot then maybe stick to what you are doing. In either case the elements to remove definitely represent a set so you probably want to keep that a set.

Comment: actually your best bet is probably to use [`SortedSet`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html) if you are fine using a third party module, would get the best of both worlds :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the list comprehension you have isn't working because you are zipping the elements together, which isn't what the operation represents (they are not parallel arrays) what you want is something along the lines of:

```
x_final = [i for i in x_irp_group[0] if (i not in x_irp_eliminated_list)]
```

Note that for a 2d list you may need to nest this like:

```
# writing normal loops you'd write:
# for row in x_irp_group:
#     for i in row:
#         if (...):
# so I typically try to indent the loops similarly since nested array comprehension
# gets complicated, honestly I'd likely prefer using generator functions for this anyway
x_final = [[i   for i in row
                    if (i not in x_irp_eliminated_list)
           ]for row in x_irp_group   
          ]
```

although know that `i not in x_irp_eliminated_list` will be very slow for a list, changing it to a set would improve performance:

```
x_irp_eliminated_set = set(x_irp_eliminated_list)
x_final = [i for i in x_irp_group[0] if (i not in x_irp_eliminated_set)]
```

Or if the lists are trivially sorted, then you could convert them both to sets, do a subtraction then sort it again:

```
x_final = [ sorted(set(x_irp_group[0]) - set(x_irp_eliminated_list)) ]
```

although if you have super giant lists this would probably be less desirable.

Comment: I used this for faster operation. Set approach made it faster. Thanks for that information. I learn one new thing. But it creates one dimensional list. I would like to create two dimensional list like original x_irp_group

Comment: I edited the nested comprehension because the first version was incorrectly collapsing a dimension, does the version that starts with `[[I for I in row` not work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
x_irp_eliminated_list_set = set(x_irp_eliminated_list)
x_last = [i for row in x_irp_group
         for i in row 
         if (i in x_irp_eliminated_list_set)]
print(x_last[:30])
```

I used this for faster operation. Set approach made it faster. Thanks for that information. I learn one new thing. But it creates one dimensional list. I would like to create two dimensional list like original x_irp_group